# mysql update on duplicate key increment

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to insert data from another table to this table. If the row exists, then I want it to increment a count value.

Here is what I have:

```
INSERT INTO bookmarks
SELECT Title, URL FROM tempt
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE CountVal=CountVal+1;
```

`bookmarks` has more columns. Both tables have `title` and `url`; `url` is the primary key.

Update 2:

I got it to work

```
insert into bookmarks (Title, URL)
SELECT Title, URL
from tempt
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE CountVal=CountVal+1;
```

but I wondering about the numbers.  I use load data in file to put the data into a temp table then I use the above code to update the actual table, but the numbers don't match and I'm wondering why that is.

Load data:  417 rows affected. 0.08 secs

insert:  810 rows affected. 0.16 secs

Any ideas?

Comment: How is this not working? Syntax error? No records in `bookmarks` get changed? CountVal is updated wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Because the columns numbers are not the same in both table, you have to specify the columns' names:

```
 INSERT INTO bookmarks (Title, URL) VALUES(
                                           SELECT Title, URL 
                                           FROM tempt
                                          )
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE CountVal=CountVal+1;
```

This will work **IF**:

- You set the identification field of `bookmarts` table to `auto_increment`
- `URL` and `Title` fields are defined in the same way in both tables
- The other columns of bookmarks table are not set to `NOT NULL`.

Comment: if using `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` no need for `VALUES()`. Use `INSERT INTO bookmarks (Title, URL) SELECT Title, URL FROM tempt ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE CountVal=CountVal+1;`

Comment: @MIvanIsten yes, but the number of columns is different in the 2 tables and we need only to pick 2 columns, so we need the `VALUES()` statement